# How should I extend the Zend Framework as a folder organisation point of view?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am currently integrating the Zend Framework in my current project named VMM.
I decided to put the Zend Framework directory as a standalone project next to my VMM project in Eclipse.
I need to do some customization of the zend framework (For example I need to add Irradiance.php into Measure) and I would like to know where is the best place to put all my customizations.

I know that I need to follow the Zend Framework naming convention and the same directory structure.
So for example Irradiance.php contain the Mylib_Measure_Irradiance class.

I was thinking to put the Mylib folder into ZendFramework/library/Mylib next to the Zend folder.

Is it the regular way to extend and customize the Zend Framework?
If not, should I put the customizations inside my VMM project or as an other standalone project?

Thanks!

---

UPDATE

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502063/how-easy-is-it-to-extend-modify-zend-framework) helped me but I still need some help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend not to put my own library style files into the ZF folder mainly because when you come to upgrade ZF you'll have to copy them all over to the new ZF.

On my localhost I have something like this

my-project is the project I am working on and contains all the models, views, controllers,etc for that project

```
/htdocs/my-project/application
/htdocs/my-project/public
```

library is my own library files and mimics the ZF structure

```
/htdocs/library/Db/
/htdocs/library/Validate/
```

I then have my current ZF in `/usr/lib/php/ZendFramework-x.xx.x` this folder contains the latest ZF and can be changed easily without changing my projects or library code base.

Edit:

David's comments about 'pointers' reminded me, I always set up a sym link in `/usr/lib/php/` called `ZendLatest`, this points to the latest copy of ZF, this means I don't have to keep changing my code or my php.ini.

Comment: Indeed. I tend to treat libraries - especially external libraries - as untouchable. Include them, use them, but don't modify anything within them, for precisely the reasons @jakenoble notes. For example, another alternative to maintaining local copies of libraries is to manage them via `svn:externals`, typivcally pointing to a tagged version. Updating to a new version becomes a simple matter of changing the pointer on the `svn:externals` property.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ressources out there:

- http://www.slideshare.net/PHPBelgium/extending-zend-framework-presentation
- http://cslai.coolsilon.com/2009/03/28/extending-zend-framework/

Comment: Yes I know the first ressource, but I was not sure that adding the Mylib folder into the ZF folder is the best solution. (Cf jakenoble answer)